# Rstudio cannot install devtools lib due to typo in a gcc link library filename. Where are link filenames kept?

Tags: r, gcc, rstudio, rstudio-server

In Rstudio server on Ubuntu 16, the devtools package is failing to install because of package build failing. This has broad impact, and is a big headache because tons of other packages need devtools, and moreover, this particular misspelled library is needed for compiling by a lot of other numerical packages too.

We can see the problem is that gcc is being somehow passed a filename to link that has a simple typo in it.  Where would be the config file that would contain the typo, so I can manually correct the spelling of the file? Do you see it below?  (This is an excerpt of the output in Rstudio when you install the devtools package, which automatically runs the gcc program.)  GCC is trying to link to the Gnu Scientific Library Basic Linear Algebra Subsystem:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lglscblas -o mime.so rawmatch.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglscblas
```

Of course the filename should say gsclblas  (for GNU scientific library) not glscblas -- RStudio has got the letter L in the wrong position obviously. There is no such file as glscblas.*

So like I said, Where would be the config file that would contain the typo, so I can manually correct the spelling? I did not type in the misspelling: It came from rstudio or some other software installation.

Thank you so much for some good information about it, if you have some.  So far this has been beyond my capability to find the file, despite searching with grep lots of ways, and digging in the Rstudio GUI, and searching on URLs like https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always taken from the `src/Makevars` file of the package you trying to build.  The devtools package has little to nothing to do with, as does RStudio.  You would probably get the *same* error via `R CMD INSTALL package_1.2-3.tar.gz`.

Now, GitHub allows us to search code for all CRAN packages (as they are mirrored there) but I am unable to find this string.

Could you share with *which package* this was in order to move us a little closer to a minimally *reproducible* example?

Comment: There is no conceivable reason why devtools would require GSL.

Comment: And it doesn't even have compiled code, see [its repo](https://github.com/hadley/devtools).

Comment: Well, then OP uses strongly confusing language. The first paragraph clearly says that they can't build devtools.

Comment: install.packages("devtools"), as I said already, was what resulted in the text which I excerpted above.

Comment: Would you be able to tell us with _which package_ that devtools may depend upon this occurred?  As I alluded to, devtools itself _does not use GSL or depend upon it_.

Comment: Thank you Dirk I have solved it. See below. No worries mate

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit the file ~/.R/Makevars

That was the hard part really.  Finding where it was.  Next...

I simply completely removed the offending argument which contained the misspelt filename.  The reason is this is OK is because BLAS libraries could speed up matrix math, but are generally optional not mandatory.  Anyway I also have faster ones than GNU's.

Thanks for everyone who were trying to stay on topic and not get too ad-hominem here!

Comment: Please just delete the question.